# Merge results horizontally in cypher queries

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two queries, each returns a table of three columns. The first two columns of two tables are similar, the third columns have different names. See the following:

```
MATCH (n:PI)-[r:SIMILAR_STUDY]->(p:PI) where ID(n) = 3162 RETURN ID(n) , ID(p),r.score as score1 ORDER BY r.score DESC LIMIT 5


ID(n)   ID(p)   score1
3162    4978    0.6666666666666666
3162    4054    0.6363636363636364
3162    4194    0.6
3162    4980    0.5555555555555556
3162    3661    0.5555555555555556
```

And:

```
MATCH (n:PI)-[r:SIMILAR_SITE]->(p:PI) where ID(n) = 3162 RETURN ID(n) ,ID(p) ,r.score as score2 ORDER BY r.score DESC LIMIT 5

ID(n)   ID(p)   score2
3162    4980    0.6
3162    3183    0.5
3162    4612    0.42857142857142855
3162    4595    0.4
3162    6926    0.4
```

How to combine these results in a unique table with 4 columns `ID(n)`, `ID(p)`, `score1`, `score2`, and also how to add an extra column for the average of scores?
Here is the expected result:

```
    ID(n)   ID(p)    score1   score2    avg
    3162    4980   0.5555555555555556   0.6    0.57
    3162    3183    0   0.5    0.25
```

Comment: You will end up with a cartesian product, which means a lot of entries will be duplicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2nd Edit:

How about using one query for both? something like:

```
MATCH (n:PI)-[:SIMILAR_STUDY|SIMILAR_SITE]->(t:PI)
WHERE ID(n) = 3162
WITH distinct t, n
OPTIONAL MATCH (t)<-[r_ste:SIMILAR_STUDY]-(n)
WITH n, t, COALESCE(r_ste.score, 0) as r1
OPTIONAL MATCH (t)<-[r_se:SIMILAR_SITE]-(n)
WITH ID(n) as n, ID(t) as t, r1, COALESCE(r_se.score, 0) as r2
WITH n, t, r1, r2, ((r1 + r2)/2) as avg 
RETURN n, t, r1, r2, avg
```

The `OPTIONAL MATCH` allows us to handle the cases with no match, and the `COALESCE` allows us to replace the `null` with 0.

To see an  example, you can use:

```
MERGE (a:PI{ID: 3162})
MERGE (b:PI{ID: 4978})
MERGE (c:PI{ID: 4054})
MERGE (d:PI{ID: 4194})
MERGE (e:PI{ID: 4980})
MERGE (f:PI{ID: 3661})
MERGE (g:PI{ID: 3183})
MERGE (h:PI{ID: 4612})
MERGE (i:PI{ID: 4595})
MERGE (j:PI{ID: 6926})

MERGE (a)-[:SIMILAR_STUDY{score: 0.6666666}]-(b)
MERGE (a)-[:SIMILAR_STUDY{score: 0.63636}]-(c)
MERGE (a)-[:SIMILAR_STUDY{score: 0.6}]-(d)
MERGE (a)-[:SIMILAR_STUDY{score: 0.55555}]-(e)
MERGE (a)-[:SIMILAR_STUDY{score: 0.55555}]-(f)
MERGE (a)-[:SIMILAR_SITE{score: 0.6}]-(e)
MERGE (a)-[:SIMILAR_SITE{score: 0.5}]-(g)
MERGE (a)-[:SIMILAR_SITE{score: 0.428}]-(h)
MERGE (a)-[:SIMILAR_SITE{score: 0.4}]-(i)
MERGE (a)-[:SIMILAR_SITE{score: 0.4}]-(j)
```

and run:

```
MATCH (n:PI)-[:SIMILAR_STUDY|SIMILAR_SITE]->(t:PI)
WHERE n.ID = 3162
WITH distinct t, n
OPTIONAL MATCH (t)<-[r_ste:SIMILAR_STUDY]-(n)
WITH n, t, COALESCE(r_ste.score, 0) as r1
OPTIONAL MATCH (t)<-[r_se:SIMILAR_SITE]-(n)
WITH n.ID as n, t.ID as t, r1, COALESCE(r_se.score, 0) as r2
WITH n, t, r1, r2, ((r1 + r2)/2) as avg 
RETURN n, t, r1, r2, avg
```

Where ID is a key on the node. With the example data I added, I get:

```
╒════╤════╤═════════╤═════╤══════════════════╕
│"n" │"t" │"r1"     │"r2" │"avg"             │
╞════╪════╪═════════╪═════╪══════════════════╡
│3162│4595│0        │0.4  │0.2               │
├────┼────┼─────────┼─────┼──────────────────┤
│3162│4054│0.63636  │0    │0.31818           │
├────┼────┼─────────┼─────┼──────────────────┤
│3162│4978│0.6666666│0    │0.3333333         │
├────┼────┼─────────┼─────┼──────────────────┤
│3162│4980│0.55555  │0.6  │0.5777749999999999│
├────┼────┼─────────┼─────┼──────────────────┤
│3162│3183│0        │0.5  │0.25              │
├────┼────┼─────────┼─────┼──────────────────┤
│3162│4612│0        │0.428│0.214             │
├────┼────┼─────────┼─────┼──────────────────┤
│3162│6926│0        │0.4  │0.2               │
├────┼────┼─────────┼─────┼──────────────────┤
│3162│3661│0.55555  │0    │0.277775          │
├────┼────┼─────────┼─────┼──────────────────┤
│3162│4194│0.6      │0    │0.3               │
└────┴────┴─────────┴─────┴──────────────────┘
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer.
What I want is a bit different. 
Actually, it is similar to OUTER JOIN in SQL of two results on the first two columns, then calculate the average on last two columns.

Comment: Thanks again, but it only for the case where two scores are available. Do you know how to consider cases when only one score available (which I prefer using zero instead of null), just similar to OUTER JOIN.

Comment: see 2nd edit :)

Comment: Works line a charm, many thanks.